как поменять расположение nuget пакетов?
С помощью команды dotnet nuget locals all --list получаю расположение пакетов:
http-cache: C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\NuGet\v3-cache
global-packages: C:\Users\user1\.nuget\packages\
temp: C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch
plugins-cache: C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\NuGet\plugins-cache

можно ли как то поменять расположение?

Документация - Переопределяет с помощью переменной среды ... - выбираете нужное, а дальше просто устанавливаете любым удобным способом нужное значение нужной переменной среды.

то есть нужно создать новые переменные среды с определенными именами или изменить существующие? К примеру у меня нет упомянутых переменных из документации

Я вам дал ссылку на документацию, где подробно все сказано. Например кэш HTTP, открываем документацию и видим Переопределяет с помощью переменной среды NUGET_HTTP_CACHE_PATH., чуть выше смотрим ссылку на параметры конфигурации и читаем там про переменные среды, там сказано какое поведение будет у конфигурации в случае наличия переменной среды, а именно Например, если переменная среды HOME в Windows имеет значение ... и Если переменная среды не найдена, NuGet использует буквальное значение из файла конфигурации.. Ну и также изучите файл nuget.config, может там есть нужное вам.
